# Sorting fields based on a composite function in Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I've an array of objects, each object has 3 Integer fields viz. `Id, Occurrences and Timestamp`, where `Timestamp` is the last time the `Id` field was accessed, and each time the `Id` field is accessed the `Occurrence`field is incremented. I'm trying to sort them in such a way such that, the most occurred item, doesn't always come in the top even if its timestamp difference is large wrt the current timestamp. So alone sorting on either `Timestamp` or `Occurrences` will always provide a biased answer. I also thought about giving some weight to each `Timestamp` and `Occurrences` and then multiplying the results and sorting them, but even that is not giving proper results, as I'm not able to guess the exact weights. What can be the best way to solve this issue ? So the the items in my list with the highest `Occurrence` and highest `Timestamp` difference move down the list as time elapses ?

Comment: can you clarify your question a bit? What exactly do you want to be on top? `that, the most occurred item, doesn't always come in the top even if its timestamp difference is large wrt the current timestamp` so which one should be on top instead? and what does wrt mean? :D

Comment: I believe we would get a better idea of what you're trying to do if you gave us some example data with your expected sort order

Comment: I feel like your entire problem is that you don't know the answer to what we're asking for and that's the answer you actually want us to give you. However, deciding which entry needs to be on top under what circumstances is up to you (or the person in charge of that assignment) and can't possibly be decided by anyone else. If you had exact requirements, estimating the needed weights should not be such a difficult thing to do.

Comment: did you try to implement `Comparator`?